# Writing Firestore Security Rule to Prevent Updating Documents to Null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to write a firestore security role that prevents a malicious user from clearing all of the data within a document via update?

I already have rules in place to prevent document deletion, but I'm worried a user could still use the "update" section of Firestore security to update documents and clear all data using Firestore's "setData" methods.

```
  match /stories/{document=**} {
      allow read, create, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.creatorID;
    }
```

Above is an example rule that I have.  Can I prevent update if the document is blank by using

```
resource.data != null || resource.data != ""
```

Or something similar?  Has anyone done this?

Comment: There is no rule that prevents something as broad as "clearing all data".  You're going to have to be specific about what a document is **allowed** or **required** to contain, in terms of its specific fields and values, and check those on every create and update. Without being specific, rules probably won't be able to help very much.

Comment: Thanks Doug, ya I decided I'm going to require certain keys exist when updating documents instead which should resolve my original issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, to resolve this I'm going to require certain keys.  For example, I'm only going to allow users to update their own data (request.auth.id == resource.id) or update certain fields (likes, follower count, etc...).

```
 match /users-metadata/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.id 
      || request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['userInvites','submission-likes','following-count', 'follower-count']);
    }
```